# Problemas al enviar datos desde puerto serial a mqtt

Tags: c++, arduino, mqtt

Describo un poco mi problema, resulta que estoy conectando de manera serial un Arduino UNO y un Node MCU con un ESP8266, el objetivo es que el Arduino uno mande datos hacia el MCU a través de conexión serial, por ahora el codigo del arduino uno es este

```
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.print("Prueba_esclavo");
    delay(500);
}
```

este codigo es para probar a mandar datos, por el otro lado tengo el node MCU que tiene este codigo

```
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "???";
const char* password = "???";

const char* MQTT_BROKER_ADRESS = "test.mosquitto.org";
const uint16_t MQTT_PORT = 1883;
const char* MQTT_CLIENT_NAME = "ArduinoClient_1";

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient mqttClient(espClient);

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const unsigned long interval = 15000;  // Intervalo de 15 segundos (en milisegundos)

void subscribeMqtt()
{
    mqttClient.subscribe("home/invernaderost/datos");
}

void onMqttReceived(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length)
{
    Serial.print("Received on ");
    Serial.print(topic);
    Serial.print(": ");

    String content = "";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        content.concat((char)payload[i]);
    }
    Serial.print(content);
    Serial.println();
}

void initMqtt()
{
    mqttClient.setServer(MQTT_BROKER_ADRESS, MQTT_PORT);
    mqttClient.setCallback(onMqttReceived);
}

void connectMqtt()
{
    Serial.print("Starting MQTT connection...");
    if (mqttClient.connect(MQTT_CLIENT_NAME))
    {
        subscribeMqtt();
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.print("Failed MQTT connection, rc=");
        Serial.print(mqttClient.state());
        Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");

        delay(5000);
    }
}

void handleMqtt()
{
    if (!mqttClient.connected())
    {
        connectMqtt();
    }
    mqttClient.loop();
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connected to WiFi. IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    initMqtt();
}

void loop()
{
    handleMqtt();

    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval)
    {
        String data = "Recibi datos " + Serial.readString();
        previousMillis = currentMillis;
        mqttClient.publish("home/invernaderost/datos", data.c_str());
    }
}
```

lo que hace el node mcu es encargarse de conectarse al wifi para posteriormente mandar datos por mqtt hacia mosquito, cuando envió datos con el método mqttClient.publish("home/invernaderost/datos", "hola mundo"); y escribo esos datos en un String se mandan correctamente los mando de esta forma mqttClient.publish("home/invernaderost/datos", data.c_str()); en el cual estoy obteniendo los datos de la consola serial y cuando se suben llegan de esta forma ���?, me gustaría que me ayudaran si es posible, ya que llevo 2 días sin poder entender el porqué de esto.

Comment: Bota el Arduino y quedate con el nodeMCU. No hay razón para tener ambos. Si te faltan pines, es más simple agregar un expansor.

Comment: Necesito expandir pines analógicos, ¿con un expansor puedo hacer eso?

Comment: Existen varios expansores. Puedes comprar el chip o la placa llegar y conectar. Busca "analog multiplexor arduino". En Aliexpress tienes este, basado en el  74HC4067, https://es.aliexpress.com/item/4000923376166.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.1.1b927a8aD4ywNg&algo_pvid=a41dd46f-b1e8-4815-bc0d-20241b444fcb&algo_exp_id=a41dd46f-b1e8-4815-bc0d-20241b444fcb-0&pdp_npi=3%40dis%21CLP%21541.0%21443.0%21%21%21%21%21%40211bd4cd16861227677614467d07fa%2110000011179686984%21sea%21CL%210&curPageLogUid=CcU2EefpRaRU